# DM Specific User ID on Discord.js Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

i'm new to coding bots and i need help on how to add a command on messaging a certain person a customized message. this is what i have so far. what should i do?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const config = require("./Data/config.json")

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] })

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('TOKEN');


client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let prefix = '??'
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split("/ +/g");
    let msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    let cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'ping')) {
        message.channel.send('pong');
    }

    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'hello')) {
        message.channel.send('hewwo uwu');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To fetch a user by id, you can use [`bot.users.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager)

To direct message a user, you can use [`User.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send):

```js
const user = await client.users.fetch(userId);
user.send("This is a DM!");
```

Comment: how do i make it for a specific user id?

Comment: I have updated my answer to more correctly answer your question

Comment: once i add that code, how do i prompt it into sending that dm? also im guessing that it should belong to clients.on right?

Comment: Yeah, this should be used in one of your commands, in the `.on("message")` listener

Comment: This will throw an error if the user has DMs disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This simple function will easily resolve the user (you can provide a user object *or* user ID so it’s very helpful)

```js
async function DMUser(resolvable, content, client) {
  const user = client.users.resolve(resolvable)
  return user.send(content)
}
//returns: message sent, or error
//usage: DMUser(UserResolvable, "content", client)
```

Related links:

[`UserManager.resolve`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=resolve)
[`User.send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send)
[`UserResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable)

Comment: where do i plug in the userid and message content?

Comment: On execute. In whatever callback you want, just do `DMUser(userid, content, client)`